# Is there a sort of standard that tells us how to order words, names, and adjectives?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Is there a sort of standard that tells us how to order words, names, and adjectives? I am not sure, but I feel like often times the best authors will put the word with the least syllables in front.

For example:

> John made a **foolhardy weird** move that almost got him killed.
>
> **Romeo and Juliette** is an extraordinary story.

Is there a sort of untold standard in writing or am I just imagining things?

Comment: There absolutely is; https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/adjective-order

Comment: To me this appears to be another question that is better suited to [English.SE] stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no particular rule on the number of syllables:

> Abercrombie and Fitch

Shakespeare normally puts the man first in his couples:

> Romeo and Juliet, Antony and Cleopatra  (but Venus and Adonis)

with adjectives, there is a general rule that the order

> General opinion, Specific opinion, Size, Shape, Age, Colour, Nationality, Material

but don't include too many adjectives in front of a noun. Three is the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations, you have rediscovered [Behaghel's Fourth Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behaghel%27s_laws) aka the Law of Increasing Constituents: "Given two phrases, when possible, the shorter precedes the longer", which is a general linguistic principle, applicable not only to English. Yakov Malkiel's paper *[Studies in irreversible binomials](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/Malkiel1959.pdf)* from 1959 formulates more rules of ordering expressions like "odds and ends".